# How to console log single object value rather then all?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, jquery-mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk, javascript-objects

I'm simply trying to fix my code. It appears when I click one of the names in the list as shown below, rather then console logging the name clicked, it will console log the name clicked, plus each name after that one. So if I click the first name, it will console log that one and every single one after, if I click the last, it will just console log that one, etc.

[image]
[image]

I'm not quite sure what it is that's going wrong. Here is my code:

```
function getGroupWall() {
    $("#groupUL").html("");
    function splitName(txt){
                var myString = txt;

                var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");

                console.log("The first element is " + mySplitResult[0]); 
                console.log("The second element is  " + mySplitResult[1]); 
                console.log("The third element is  " + mySplitResult[2]); 

    };
    FB.api('/421727124532461/feed?limit=5', 'get', function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        for (i=0; j=response.data.length; i++) {
            $("#groupUL").append("<li>" + "<h4>Item Description:</h4> " + response.data[i].message + "<br /> " + "<h2>Posted By:</h2> <a href='#' class='splitNames'>" + response.data[i].from.name + "</a>" + "<br />"+ "<h4># of Replys: </h4>" + response.data[i].comments.count + "<br />" +  "<a href='" + response.data[i].link + "' target='new' style='text-align:right;'>(external url)</a>" + "<br /> " + "<img src='"+response.data[i].picture+"'>" + "</li><br />");
            $(".splitNames").click((function (item) {
                return function (event) {
                    splitName(item.from.name)
                }
            }(response.data[i])));
        }
    });
}
```

Also I get this error:
[image]

... But it seems to be displaying the # of replys fine? As shown here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNtRt.png]

Comment: doesn't splitName function console log always?

Comment: sorry meant console.log everything ;)